# How to remove parent entity without child in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I used on `@OneToMany` relation `cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE` but it removes parent entity and all the childs whereas I wouldn't  love to remove child entities (but only parent) : how to do that?

Is there any efficient solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to clean the relationship before:

```
parent.setChildren(null);
entityManager.remove(parent);
```

There is no such "quick/smart" solution when we talk about remove parent without touching the children.